# tikz xbar extra coordinate

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to plot a comparison of numbers with

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xbar,
        y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
        axis x line       = none,
        tickwidth         = 0pt,
        enlarge y limits  = 0.2,
        enlarge x limits  = 0.02,
        symbolic y coords = {SRE, SWB},
        nodes near coords,
    ]
        \addplot coordinates { (36470,SRE)     (33039,SWB) };
        \addplot coordinates { (30460,SRE)     (25876,SWB) };
        \addplot coordinates { (25640,SRE)     (21761,SWB) };
        \legend{Combined, 2phnn, 1phnn}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but the result I get so far is this

[image: wrong result]

I'd like to move the labels because it's hiding stuff and I don't understand why an extra 'SWB' is showing up

Comment: Add `ytick=data` or `ytick={SWB,SRE}` to the options of the `axis` environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As esdd mentions in a comment, adding `ytick=data` will add ticks only at the specified data values. To move the legend, add something like `legend style={at={(rel axis cs:1,0.5)},anchor=east}` to the `axis` options.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xbar,
        y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
        axis x line       = none,
        tickwidth         = 0pt,
        enlarge y limits  = 0.2,
        enlarge x limits  = 0.02,
        symbolic y coords = {SRE, SWB},
        nodes near coords,
        ytick=data,
        legend style={at={(rel axis cs:1,0.5)},anchor=east}
    ]
        \addplot coordinates { (36470,SRE)     (33039,SWB) };
        \addplot coordinates { (30460,SRE)     (25876,SWB) };
        \addplot coordinates { (25640,SRE)     (21761,SWB) };
        \legend{Combined, 2phnn, 1phnn}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is a variation with a bit less whitespace:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xbar,
        height=5cm,width=8cm, % added
        y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
        axis x line       = none,
        tickwidth         = 0pt,
        enlarge y limits  = 0.7, % modified
        enlarge x limits  = 0.02,
        symbolic y coords = {SRE, SWB},
        nodes near coords,
        ytick=data,
         legend style={
            at={(rel axis cs:0.5,1)},
            anchor=south,
            legend columns=-1, % -1 means place all in a row
            column sep=2mm, % more space
            draw=none % removes frame
            }
    ]
        \addplot coordinates { (36470,SRE)     (33039,SWB) };
        \addplot coordinates { (30460,SRE)     (25876,SWB) };
        \addplot coordinates { (25640,SRE)     (21761,SWB) };
        \legend{Combined, 2phnn, 1phnn}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```