# pgfplots: Scale x-axis (manually set x-axis limits, min/max)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I created several horizontal bar plots with percentages. Is there a way to force the x-axis from 0 to 100 for easier comparing to the other graphs?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xbar,
y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
axis x line       = none,
tickwidth         = 0pt,
enlarge y limits  = 0.33,
enlarge x limits  = 0.02,
symbolic y coords = {A, B, C},
nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal}]
\addplot[fill = black] coordinates { (43.0,A)   (30.1,B) (41.7,C)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Sure, just add `xmin=0` and `xmax=100` to the `axis` options.

Comment: I adapted your title according to what I think is more appropriate.

Comment: To complete Stefan Pinnow's answer, also add `xmin=0` to the options

Comment: @BambOo, in the meantime I added that to my comment;)

Comment: ...and if you manually chose the x range, probably `enlarge x limits` should be removed...

Comment: @StefanPinnow May I post an answer? This is an easy one and otherwise I can't compete with you guys :).

Comment: @StefanPinnow I posted an answer. I remove it if you don't like it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- This can be easily done with the option pair `xmin` and `xmax`.
- It looks like your code is based on [tikz xbar extra coordinate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317519). If yes, then please indicate this the next time.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\section*{Original Code from Question}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xbar,
y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
axis x line       = none,
tickwidth         = 0pt,
enlarge y limits  = 0.33,
enlarge x limits  = 0.02,
symbolic y coords = {A, B, C},
nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal}]
\addplot[fill = black] coordinates { (43.0,A)   (30.1,B) (41.7,C)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\section*{Modified Code}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [
            xbar,
            y axis line style = {opacity = 0},
            axis x line  = none,            
            tickwidth = 0pt,
            %enlarge y limits  = 0.33, % <-- removed due to suggestion of user https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38080/rmano 
            %enlarge x limits  = 0.02, % <-- removed due to suggestion of user https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38080/rmano 
            xmin = 0, % <-- added
            xmax = 100, % <-- added
            symbolic y coords = {A, B, C},
            nodes near coords, 
            nodes near coords align = {horizontal},
        ]
    % Plot
    \addplot
        [
            fill = black
        ] 
        coordinates 
            {
                (43.0,A)   
                (30.1,B) 
                (41.7,C)
            };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Strange Things

1. Additional y ticks appeared after my modification. `-->` `ytick = data,` helps (see [tikz xbar extra coordinate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317519) for example).
2. Using `(43.0, A)` instead of `(43.0,A)` (additional space) leads to an error message.

   ! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the input coordinate ` A' has not been defined
   with 'symbolic y coords={A, B, C}... Maybe it has been misspelled? Or did you
   mean something like [normalized] A?.

---

### Updated code for "Strang(er) Things 1" (unwanted additional y-ticks removed)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [
            xbar,
            y axis line style = {opacity = 0},
            axis x line  = none,            
            tickwidth = 0pt,
            %enlarge y limits  = 0.33, % <-- removed due to suggestion of user https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38080/rmano 
            %enlarge x limits  = 0.02, % <-- removed due to suggestion of user https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38080/rmano 
            xmin = 0, % <-- added
            xmax = 100, % <-- added
            ytick = data, % <-- added
            symbolic y coords = {A, B, C},
            nodes near coords, 
            nodes near coords align = {horizontal},
        ]
    % Plot
    \addplot
        [
            fill = black
        ] 
        coordinates 
            {
                (43.0,A)   
                (30.1,B) 
                (41.7,C)
            };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

### Update after Stefan Pinnow's Comment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [
            height = 30mm, % added after Stefan Pinnow's comment
            width = \axisdefaultwidth, % added after Stefan Pinnow's comment
            xbar,
            % y axis line style = {opacity = 0}, removed after Stefan Pinnow's comment
            draw = none, % added after Stefan Pinnow's comment
            axis x line  = none,            
            tickwidth = 0pt,
            %enlarge y limits  = 0.33, % <-- removed due to suggestion of user https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38080/rmano 
            %enlarge x limits  = 0.02, % <-- removed due to suggestion of user https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38080/rmano 
            xmin = 0, % <-- added
            xmax = 100, % <-- added
            % ytick = data, % <-- added and later removed after Stefan Pinnow's comment
            ytick distance = 1, % <-- added instead after Stefan Pinnow's comment
            symbolic y coords = {A, B, C},
            nodes near coords, 
            nodes near coords align = {horizontal},
        ]
    % Plot
    \addplot
        [
            fill = black
        ] 
        coordinates 
            {
                (43.0,A)   
                (30.1,B) 
                (41.7,C)
            };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course you can. But since you decided to answer, now hopefully you will learn a bit (more): **1.** Because OP stated that he has more than one of these plots, instead of writing `ytick=data` I would recommend using `ytick distance=1`. This also avoids additional `yticks`. Then also for plots were one bar is absent (not in the `\addplot coordinate` list, the plot will look the same. **2.** Instead of using`opacity=0` to don't show the *y*-axis line I would use `draw=none`. ...

Comment: ... **3.** To make the graphs look nicer I would add something like `height=3cm`. But to keep the *same* width then you also need to add `width=\axisdefaultwidth`. **4.** Then it is a matter of taste to remove the `enlarge ... limits` stuff or play around a bit with the values like `enlarge x limits=0.02` and/or `enlarge y limits=0.1`.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Thanks for the hints! I updated the code accordingly (1. to 3.). About the `draw = none,` I also tried this in an earlier version of the answer but it changed the look of the output (added two vertical lines) and I wasn't sure if the OP wants that. In addition, since a 100k+ user in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317519 did not complain about `y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },` I thought/assumed that it is ok :).